# No funciona recuperar nombres de las bases de datos de MySql utilizando getMetaData().getCatalogs()

Tags: java, jdbc

> Realizo la conexion en segundo plano

```
 private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Connection> {
    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(Void... strings) {
        try {
```

> Me conecto al servidor donde esta alojado mi bd utilizando el driver correspondiente

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://6.80.194.171:3306","casa", "" );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conexion;
    }
```

> Interactuo con la parte grafica, para mostrar en los "Toast" los nombres de las bases de datos que tiene asignado el usuario

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Connection respuesta) {
        super.onPostExecute(respuesta);
        if(conexion!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = respuesta.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rsa = meta.getCatalogs();
            String nombreDB;
```

> No me muestra nada

```
            while(rsa.next()){
                nombreDB = rsa.getString("TABLE_CAT");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),nombreDB,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> Porfavor ayuda, en todas partes lo hacen de esta manera, pero a mi no me funciona!!

Answer (score 0):

> RESUELTO!!! Es lo que habia sospechado, debia de recuperar los nombres de las bases de datos en el doInBackground. Dejo el codigo aqui:

```
 protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... strings) {
        ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://6.80.194.171:3306","casa", "" );
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conexion.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rsa = meta.getCatalogs();
            for(int i=0; rsa.next(); i++) {
                nombres.add(rsa.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nombres;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> respuesta) {
        super.onPostExecute(respuesta);
        for(int i=0; respuesta.size()>i; i++){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),respuesta.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

> Alguien me resuelve la duda de porque es necesario recuperar los metadatos de la conexion en el background?. Un saludo